# How to require another `rb` file when using `rails runner`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I write a task `foo.rb` that require `bar.rb`.
I can require the `.rb` file by `require './bar'` in normal ruby environments.

When I run the script as a task of rails app by `rails runner lib/tasks/foo.rb`, then It fails with this error.

`require': cannot load such file -- ./foo (LoadError)

I tried also `require 'lib/task/broker'`, but it ends up same error.

To load files I added in `config/application.rb` this code.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

How should I require a `.rb` file in the same directory when `rails runner` is used?

Answer (score 0):

Use `require_relative` to load files using relative path.

Example:

```
require_relative './bar'
```